# fourier transform of positive function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am having trouble with this question:

Show that there exists a compactly supported $C^\infty$ function $\phi$ on $\mathbf{R}$ such that $\phi \ge 0, \phi(0) >0$, and $\hat{\phi} \ge 0$.

I know that $\phi = e^{-\pi x^2}$ would work since $\hat{\phi} = e^{-\pi x^2}$ but this $\phi$ is not compactly supported...

Comment: can't you try to use a bump function that has a cut-off somewhere?

Comment: Take a compactly supported function and convolve it with itself; this will make the FT nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks! Actually is it more precise to convolve $f$ with $g(x):=\overline{f}(-x)$?

Comment: @SingfookSangwood: If $f$ is real and even, $\hat f$ is real so $\widehat{f\ast f}=\hat f^2\ge0$.